# AS3 class : access of undefined method / property errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this class :

```
package  {

    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class gestioneMultilingua 
    {
        public static function settaLingua(lingua:String):void
        {
            var dati:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("datiApp", "/");
            dati.data.lingua = lingua;
            dati.flush();
        }

        public static function applicaFiltriLingua():void 
        {
            var dati:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("datiApp", "/");
            var lingua : String = dati.data.lingua;

            for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++){
                var e:Object = getChildAt(i);

                if(e.name.indexOf("$"+lingua) >= 0){
                    e.visible = true;
                }
                else if(e.name.indexOf("$")  >= 0){
                    e.visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I got these errors :

[image]

How can I fix them ? maybe I need to import a package ?

Comment: your class doesnt have those methods, you forgot to extend Sprite or MovieClip etc.

Comment: if i extends MovieClip i recive the error : the definition of base class MovieClip was not found

Comment: but do you import this class then `import flash.display.Sprite;` or `import flash.display.MovieClip;`? Also MovieClip is for objects with timeline, you want to use Sprite instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static function without any problem when you use it correctly of course, the problem here is not that the function is static (and not using `numChildren` or calling `getChildAt()` in that static function) but it is about how you did all that.

In your case, you want to work with a [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html)'s children, so you can simply pass that object to your `applicaFiltriLingua()` function like this :

```
public static function applicaFiltriLingua(container:DisplayObjectContainer):void 
{
    var dati:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("datiApp","/");
    var lingua:String = dati.data.lingua;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++) 
    {
        var e:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);
        if (e.name.indexOf("$" + lingua) >= 0) {
            e.visible = true;
        } else if (e.name.indexOf("$")  >= 0) {
            e.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can call your function without any problem, like this, for example :

```
import gestioneMultilingua;

gestioneMultilingua.applicaFiltriLingua(this);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: @AlessandroZago You have to import that class of course ! Try to do some effort man !

Comment: ok man now works with non static methods, but with static : no. this is the code : http://prntscr.com/9bp4k1 i think the static method don't use imported library

Comment: @AlessandroZago Even with static method, that should work ! Your last code (attached to your last comment) is working or not ?

Comment: @AlessandroZago Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Did you see my code example ? You have to use your appropriate `DisplayObjectContainer` ( your Sprite, MovieClip, ... ) instead of `this` in my last code ...

Comment: the method works if i use NON STATIC methods but don't work if i use static methods

Comment: @AlessandroZago There is no condition to use it with a non static methods ! I tested it and it's working well ! So, how did you tried it with static methods ?

Answer (score 1):

A static method can only make calls to another static method. numChildren and getChildAt are not static methods and calling them from inside a static method can only produce errors. Even if your class was extending a DisplayObjectContainer it will still get those errors since instances of that class will have getChildAt method and numChildren property but at static level those would still not exist and would still produce errors.

Do not make your applicaFiltriLingua method static and extend a valid DisplayObjectContainer

Comment: ok but extend a valid DisplayObjectContainer? please can you link me an example?

Comment: MovieClip or Sprite are valid DisplayObjectContainer

Comment: and how can i pass the entire MovieClip to my class?

Comment: @BotMaster I don't agree with you. What about doing it as what I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34147998/2256820) ?

Comment: Sure you can, I based my answer on the fact that the user doesn't know what a static method really is and how to use it,

Answer (score 1):

Since your function is a STATIC you can never instantiate one and non-static fields of all types are not allowed. Instance constructors are also not allowed and the class is automatically sealed.

Make method non-static and instantiate the class "gestioneMultilingua"

`var multilingua:gestioneMultilingua = new gestioneMultilingua();`

than you can access it like that multilingua.applicaFiltriLingua(//reference to stage)
and 
do

```
public function applicaFiltriLingua(stage_ref:MovieClip):void
{
    var dati:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("datiApp", "/");
    var lingua : String = dati.data.lingua;

    for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++){
        var e:Object = stage_ref.getChildAt(i);
        if(e.name.indexOf("$"+lingua) >= 0){
            e.visible = true;
        }
        else if(e.name.indexOf("$")  >= 0){
            e.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i pass to stage_ref all my stage?

Comment: i have call the method : multilingua.applicaFiltriLingua(this.MovieClip);

Comment: but : trace(numChildren); = 0